# git clone: fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:

Tags: gitlab, git-clone

I am trying to clone the gitlab to my local library. While doing the cloning am getting the error, "fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for:"," redirect:usersign link".
Can any one let me know how to get resolve this issue

Comment: What url are you trying to hit?

Comment: Hi, The URL which we used internal for our project.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, i could able to resolve this.
**While pasting the URL -- we should not use the Direct URL from the Browser**.

1. Select the Branch which you wanted to get the Clone of.
2. Go to the Repository -- on the Top left corner -- Click on the Icon with three dots(...) called ACTION Menu -- Select Clone.
3. Here you will get an URL with your username.
4. Copy this URL and paste it on the GitBash cmd prompt.

   Ex: git clone https://{username}@{website}.com/1/2/3/4.git
5. Hit Enter.

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing the same issue and found that everything was correct from my end. Then i realized that i was not connected to my company's vpn. I tried after connecting the vpn and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error.

I figured out that I was passing the target URL from the browser instead of the clone option from the left pane of the repository web page.

Click on the Clone button and copy the target URL and pass that URL in the - git clone command

git clone

Comment: Your answer looks right. But your english is not correct. If I where you I will write something like "Please make git clone to other folder and remove the first."

Answer (score 0):

Set the *http.proxy* parameter for your proxy:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://DOMAIN\username@proxy-server.domain:8080
```

Comment: hi voa in DOMAIN and username do i need to put my custom info